# issue in element binding

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="Trainning.biding"
x:Name="Window"
Title="biding"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="8,8,0,8" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource kirupaZuneDataSampleDataSource}}">
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Height="48" Margin="99,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="96">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="#FF13428D"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="#00FFFFFF" Background="#00166A13"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="#FF890E6F" Background="#0005116E"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="#0005116E" Background="#0009683A"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="##0009683A"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox Margin="99,145,297,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox}" Height="41" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

it's output will be like the below figure

[image: element_binding]

but exactly i need to bind the string "#FF13428D" into textbox.

what should i do for that...please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=comboBox}"
```

to access the content of the selected combobox item.